# What should I do with an unfinished parquet floor during a two-year rental?

Tags: wood, floor, hardwood-floor

I'm renting an apartment and I've just moved in.

The apartment's floor is a wooden parquet floor and it appears to have been polished/sanded but it doesn't seem to have any sort of finish on it, so I have no clue of how to take care of it for the following two years (until my lease ends) since the only wooden floors I've know were all lacquered or varnished.

(I will post some pictures as soon as I can)

Comment: Ask your landlord (or the maintenance person for the building)

Comment: I'm with Ecnerwal, You should do nothing to a floor in a house you're renting. Only the entity charged with property management is responsible for/has the authority to do work like that.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've spoken to the leasing company and they to told me to "just use a wax for clear wooden floors", so I guess I'll be doing that. I have no clue how to properly apply it or what tools do I need (if any), but I'll be researching that aside from this question. So thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would find it hard to believe that someone would sand a wood floor but then neglect to put a protective finish on it (unless this is a very rustic building like a barn?). It's possible there's varnish there but it's not a glossy type. An unfinished wood floor seems like a negligent decision by the landlord and a bad investment on their part. I would check with him/her. I don't know where you live or what the landlord/tenant laws are, but in general at the end of your lease you are *not* required to leave the property in pristine condition: normal "wear and tear" (for which you are not responsible) would be considerably higher for an unfinished floor.

In any event, the best thing you can do for any wood floor (regardless of finish) is to keep it clean. If you let sand and dirt accumulate they will act like sandpaper and wear the surface away much more quickly.